# Many values in XML value field

Tags: xml, log4j, syslog, appender

```
  <appender name="LOGSTASH" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
    <param name="facility" value="SYSLOG"/>
    <param name="SyslogHost" value="" />
    <param name ="loggerFields" value =" ????? "/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern"
       value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %p %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

I have a xml file like this, and I have to keep in value of "loggerFields" something like this:

```
<pair key="THREAD_ID" value="%X{threadId}"/>
```

I know that "loggerFields" takes list of KeyValuePairs, but i have no idea how can i write it.

What is the best way to obtain this effect?

Answer (score 1):

### Use nested `LoggerFields` containing `KeyValuePairs`:

```
    <param name ="loggerFields">
        <LoggerFields>
            <KeyValuePair key="thread" value="%t"/>
            <KeyValuePair key="priority" value="%p"/>
            <KeyValuePair key="category" value="%c"/>
        </LoggerFields>
    </param>
```

See [log4j documentation for SyslogAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender):

> Allows arbitrary PatternLayout patterns to be included as specified
>   ThreadContext fields; no default specified. To use, include a
>   `LoggerFields` nested element, containing one or more `KeyValuePair` elements. Each `KeyValuePair` must have a key attribute, which
>   specifies the key name which will be used to identify the field within
>   the MDC Structured Data element, and a value attribute, which
>   specifies the PatternLayout pattern to use as the value.

Comment: It isn't working on log4j 1.2. I forget write about this in first post.

Comment: @kjhughes Any idea/example about using LoggerFields inside log4j2.properties ? 

I tried several combination and nothing on doc any were ..

Comment: @AnkushTehale: Please ask a new question.  Thanks.

Comment: Here is new question..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822739/loggerfields-for-syslog-with-log4j2-properties-file

Answer (score 0):

As alternative, you can use the GELF protocol. This allows you some more flexibility and is more resilient to your application since it uses TCP and not UDP. It won't block your application when logstash is down/not reachable. All you need is the GelfAppender Jar (https://github.com/mp911de/logstash-gelf/releases/tag/logstash-gelf-1.6.0) and this snippet in your log4j config:

```
<appender name="gelf" class="biz.paluch.logging.gelf.log4j.GelfLogAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
    <param name="Host" value="udp:localhost" />
    <param name="Port" value="12201" />
    <param name="Version" value="1.1" />
    <param name="Facility" value="java-test" />
    <param name="ExtractStackTrace" value="true" />
    <param name="TimestampPattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSS" />

    <!-- This are static fields -->
    <param name="AdditionalFields" value="fieldName1=fieldValue1,fieldName2=fieldValue2" />

    <!-- This are fields using MDC -->
    <param name="MdcFields" value="mdcField1,mdcField2" />
    <param name="DynamicMdcFields" value="mdc.*,(mdc|MDC)fields" />
    <param name="IncludeFullMdc" value="true" />
</appender>
```