# LoggerFields for Syslog with log4j2.properties file

Tags: log4j2, rsyslog

There are examples for log4j2 syslog for adding priority to log with xml using key, value but with `log4j.properties` files we can't add `=` symbol to value and I haven't any example to set LoggerFields for setting priority with RFS5454 format.

This one is close [LoggerFields for Syslog (output log priority and stack trace)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244901/loggerfields-for-syslog-output-log-priority-and-stack-trace)

None of the below works for LoggerField:

appender.sumo_syslog.loggerFields={'key' : 'priority', 'value' : '%p'} 
or 
appender.sumo_syslog.loggerFields=[{'key' : 'priority', 'value' : '%p'}] 
or
appender.sumo_syslog.loggerFields.keyValuePair={'key' : 'priority', 'value' : '%p'}

Comment: appender.sumo_syslog.type = Syslog
appender.sumo_syslog.name = sumo_syslog\n
#appender.sumo_syslog.layout.type = PatternLayout\n
#appender.sumo_syslog.layout.pattern = %-5p %-25c{1.} %marker%m%n\n
appender.sumo_syslog.port = 514\n
appender.sumo_syslog.host = localhost\n
appender.sumo_syslog.facility = local6\n
appender.sumo_syslog.protocol = UDP\n
appender.sumo_syslog.format = RFC5424\n
appender.sumo_syslog.appName="es-5x"\n
appender.sumo_syslog.mdcId="mcd"\n
appender.sumo_syslog.charset = UTF-8\n

Comment: None of the below works:

appender.sumo_syslog.loggerFields={'key' : 'priority', 'value' : '%p'}

or
appender.sumo_syslog.loggerFields=[{'key' : 'priority', 'value' : '%p'}]
appender.sumo_syslog.loggerFields.keyValuePair={'key' : 'priority', 'value' : '%p'}

Answer (score 4):

You can to use this way:

```
appender.syslog.type = Syslog
appender.syslog.name = syslog
appender.syslog.facility = LOCAL0 
appender.syslog.host = X.X.X.X
appender.syslog.appName = API-TEST
appender.syslog.enterpriseNumber = 18060
appender.syslog.port = 514
appender.syslog.newLine = true
appender.syslog.protocol = TCP
appender.syslog.format = RFC5424
appender.syslog.messageId = Audit
appender.syslog.id = system1
appender.syslog.mdcId = mdc
appender.syslog.layout.type = loggerFields
appender.syslog.layout.pairs.type = KeyValuePair
appender.syslog.layout.pairs.key = category
appender.syslog.layout.pairs.value = %c
appender.syslog.layout.pairs2.type = KeyValuePair
appender.syslog.layout.pairs2.key = message
appender.syslog.layout.pairs2.value = %m
appender.syslog.layout.pairs3.type = KeyValuePair
appender.syslog.layout.pairs3.key = exception
appender.syslog.layout.pairs3.value = %ex
```

Comment: This is an answer, and it may be a valid answer. However, it is not a very good answer because it does not explain why this answer works.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.